# Writing my first React program, Any user interface is not rendering on browser

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create my first sample using React [tutorial](https://www.kirupa.com/react/building_your_first_react_app.htm). This is the code i have written on a text edit file and saved it as Day.html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <script type="text/babel">
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Alok upadhyay</h1>,
  document.body
);

  </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

When i am running this file by double clicking on day1.html, it just shows the same html loaded on web. Attached output:

[image: Output]

It should show **Alok upadhyay**. I have tried it on chrome, safari and firefox but it is not working at all.

Any advice!
Thanks

Comment: I tried it locally (chrome on ubuntu) and it did work correctly

Comment: @AydinK. i attached screen shot

Comment: Think this has smt to do with the file extension. This will happen when the extension is `.txt` or smt like that. You can try to rename it and make sure that it's really `.html`